# How do I generally take a full device snapshot?

Tags: backup

I've just recently replaced my phones and tablet with newer Android devices, notably:

- AT&T Samsung Galaxy Note 3
- AT&T Samsung Galaxy S5
- Google Nexus 7 (2013) with LTE

With new devices of anything, I generally like to make a "clean-slate" full backup so as to always be able to return to zero.

Is there a universal way to create restorable full-device backups in Android?

If not, at least how can I do it for the given devices?

Comment: As you've correctly used the `backup` tag, did you check [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info)? It's all there :) Check for "Nandroid". Unfortunately, it's a chicken-egg-thing: To make such a snapshot of a "virgin device", you first have to modify it (Nandroid doesn't ship with stock Android, so you'll need to install a custom recovery).

Comment: Also, stock firmware images are *technically* restorable, but only with the help of a PC. Use ODIN for Samsung, and Fastboot for the Nexus.